# Checkmarx "Client Dom Code Injection" on JavaScript ajax method

Tags: javascript, checkmarx

I have the following code that is being flagged by Checkmarx as a `Client Dom Code Injection` security problem. Checkmarx is pointing to the `result.Error` line as being the possible injection point and we don't understand why.

Why is this happening and what can we do to resolve this?

```
function GetEmployeeDelegates() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: SITE_ROOT + 'Form/GetEmployeeDelegates/',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Error == "") {
                $(".menu-loading").hide();
            } else { }
        },
        error: function (error) {
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });


}
```

Comment: Can you maybe share the entire flow that being presented by Checkmarx? It may help understanding how to assist you.

Comment: What do you mean by the entire flow?

Comment: I mean the full attack vector.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean, sorry about that.

Here is all the other info I have.

Method function at line 139 of \Scripts\ESC.js gets a client-side controlled data for the result element. This element’s value is used in client-side code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually integrated into the HTML code in function at line 139 of \Scripts\ESC.js.